# Installing Istio on a project-level

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, istio

Is it possible to install Istio on a project-level? Every Istio installation guide I see is cluster-wide. But since multiple departments share the same cluster in my company that is not an option.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make any sense. So multiple departments have access to a cluster, and you want to solve it by installing Istio at project level, where (probably) even more users have access to? Besides, that's why there are RBAC rules.

Comment: What? To my understanding, in OpenShift, multiple projects share the same cluster. Thanks for the -1.

Comment: OK. Let's assume you can do that. Now you have installed Istio at project level. From your project, 20% of users should have access to the cluster, but the remaining 80% shouldn't (for example), or from your k8s users 20% should have access to Istio, while the remaining 80% shouldn't. How do you solve that problem? You can say I just don't give them access to the cluster. Then don't give them from the very beginning. Still doesn't make sense to me. You need to use RBAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Istio is installed in one namespace but is not necessarily working for all the cluster. Actually, Istio works only for those workloads that have the Istio sidecar injected.

For example, the following command will create some Deployments (and thus, pods) that will have the Istio Sidecar injected. Those pods will have enabled the whole Istio features.

```
kubectl apply -f <(./bin/istioctl kube-inject -f samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml) -n bookinfo
```

However, the following command won't inject the Istio sidecar and as a consequence, Istio control plane won't modify their behavior.

```
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml -n bookinfo
```

In order to manage the incoming/outgoing traffic to the istio service mesh, you can create Istio Gateways (edge of the mesh): https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/gateway/

Also related to traffic ingress, Istio has its own istio-ingressgateway (similar to K8S Ingress Resource but without any default traffic rule applied):
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/

The rest of the traffic not going through these ways, won't be part of the traffic managed by Istio Service Mesh.

In order to test that, you can easily install the default Istio demo `bookinfo` without sidecars (second command above) and see that there is no telemetry registered and no tracing data. If you are using Kiali (www.kiali.io) you are going to see that the service graph shows empty and desconnected (meaning that there is no telemetry registered).

[image: Service Graph in Kiali for pods outside of service mesh]

Also, you can expose any service of bookinfo and consume them without any Istio interacting:

[image: Calling Ratings service where sidecar is not injected]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if your project has its own namespace. You would just enable istio for that namespace:

```
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: yourapp
  labels:
    app: yourapp
    istio-injection: enabled
```